# How to get two xml files in a single array collection in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, arraycollection

I have two xml files, defect. xml and employee.xml. But the files havea common field but with different names in each file. I want both the files to be merged in to a single array collection.

The structure of my defect.xml file is:

```
<defectList>
    <defect>
           <revId>123</revId> 
           <revType>IQA</revType> 
           <status>Review Pending</status> 
           <assignedTo>Angeline</assignedTo> 
           <loggedBy>chandran</loggedBy> 
           <closedDate>13-10-2009</closedDate> 
   </defect>
   <defect>
           <revId>124</revId> 
           <revType>IQA</revType> 
           <status>Review Pending</status> 
           <assignedTo>Aarthi</assignedTo> 
           <loggedBy>chandran</loggedBy> 
           <closedDate>15-10-2009</closedDate> 
   </defect>

<defectList>
```

And my employee.xml

```
 <Employees>
      <employee>
               <employeeId>256148</employeeId> 
               <employeeName>Angeline</employeeName> 
      </employee>
      <employee>
               <employeeId>256158</employeeId> 
               <employeeName>Aarthi</employeeName> 
      </employee>

<Employees>
```

I get both the xml files in two array collections:

```
 <mx:Model id="employeeXML" source="assets/employee.xml"/>
 <mx:ArrayCollection id="employeeList" source="{employeeXML.employee}"/>

 <mx:Model id="defectXML" source="assets/defect.xml"/>
 <mx:ArrayCollection id="defectList" source="{defectXML.defect}"/>
```

when "assignedTo" matches "employeeName", I want the "employeeId" to be added to the defectList array collection. How can I do this? 
How to iteerate through an array collection?

And how to check if the assignedTo field in defectList equals employeeName field in employeeList? Some one guide me..

**EDIT**

ok, Now I'm able to compare the two fields,assignedTo of defectList and employeeName of employeeList.Thanks to Simon:

```
 var defect:Object; 
 var employee:Object; 
for each (defect in defectList) 
{ 
    for each (employee in employeeList) 
    { 
        if(defect.assignedTo == employee.employeeName)
        {
             // defectList.addItem(employee.employeeId);
               // I tried this,but it is wrong .
        }
   } 
}
```

But how to add the employeeId field to that particular array element,so that I could use defectList as the dataprovider for the datagrid n display employee Id also? Can someone help me with this.

**SOLUTION**

I have found out the solution. Here is the code:

```
public function init():void{
            var defect:Object; 
            var employee:Object; 

                for each (defect in defectList) 
                { 
                    for each (employee in employeeList) 
                    { 
                        if(defect.assignedTo == employee.employeeName)
                        {
                            var id:Object;
                            id=employee.employeeId;
                            defect["employeeId"]=id;    
                        }  
                    } 
                }
        }
```

Now, if I give datafield as "employeeId" in the datagrid with defectList as dataprovider, I get the employee id of the corresponding Employee Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer part of this...

Iterating through an ArrayCollection is easy...

```
var defect:Object;
var employee:Object;
for each (defect in defectList)
{
    for each (employee in employeeList)
    {
        // do your check here.
    }
}
```

You need to be careful with iterators like ForEach if you are hanging the contents of the arrays as you iterate.  You may want to consider loading up a third array as you go.

I'm not sure exactly how you get at the element values from  the XML objects created in your code snippet, but there is a lot of help on the [Adobe Livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/XML.html)

You might be able to use the fact that an object can have its fields reference in a late-binded way...

```
var elementContents:String = employee["employeeName"];
```

Comment: ok, I am able to compare the elements. thats for that. But how to add the field "EmployeeId" to the defectList array collection? Any idea?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I found the solution :-)